# Blender 2.91 UV Editor. Rip edges keeping them in the same position fails

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to rip edges or faces from a UV map and keeping them in the same position to move the whole created island afterwards.

If I try to do that by Selection the edges or faces I want to Rip, press V and then press RMC the ripping process doesn't happen. This operation works well in edit mode. You can click any edge press V and then RMC. The geometry remains in the same place but the "cut" has been done. After that, you can select the whole polygon island by clicking Ctrl+L.

However, in UVedit mode if you press RMC instead of moving the edges and you try to select the UV island you can check the whole UV island is still joined to the whole group and everything is selected.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it seems like a bug, sorta, I tested and the rip actually works, but once the selection changes, the UV vertices gets joined again (because they are at the exact same place)

tested and worked workaround is to move it a very small amount, like .0001, but not too small so that it doesn't round to zero

Comment: Thanks for that! 
The work around will certainly help.

Is there a way I should report this bug to be fixed in upcoming updates?

Comment: You are welcome, sure here's where to report bugs: https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/
and a video guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Perfect!

Thanks again :)